# Best wordpress plugin for google analytics?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I want to implement google analytics in my project. Please suggest a best wordpress plugin to implement this feature.

Comment: used  "https://wordpress.org/plugins/googleanalytics/"

Comment: @Tarangkoradiya Is it best one to implement

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Google Analytics plugins for Wordpress, in order of the number of downloads.

[1. Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)By Alin Marcu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/)

[2. Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)

[3. Google Analytics Dashboard Plugin for WordPress By Analytify (free)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-analytify/)

[4. Analytify Premium version](https://analytify.io/)

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Rahul's list, if you're looking to measure more than just page hits, I would check out the [IntelligenceWP plugin by LevelTen Interactive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/intelligence/).